# Función para arrojar Errores en Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
// Agrega un accesorio a un gatito  
// Si el gato no existe arrojar un Error ('El gato <nombre_gato> no existe')  
// Si el gato ya tiene puesto el accesorio, arrojar un Error('El gato <nombre_gato> ya tiene el accesorio puesto') y no lo agrega  
// Si el accesorio fue agregado correctamente retornar un mensaje: 'El accesorio <tipo_accesorio> fue agregado a <nombre_gato> con exito'


addCatAccessory: function (catName, catAccessory) {
  const nameCat = cats.find(cat => cat.name === catName);
  if(!nameCat) throw new Error(`El gato ${catName} no existe`);
    
  const  newAcces = cats.find(access => access.accessories === catAccessory);   
  if(newAcces){
    throw new Error(`El gato ${catName} ya tiene el accesorio puesto`)
  }
  cats.push(catAccessory);
  return `El accesorio ${cats.accessories} fue agregado a ${catName} con exito`
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema????

Comment: Esta pregunta necesita detalles y aclaraciones.

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que `cats` tiene esta estructura:

```
let cats=[
           {name:'Misu', accessories:[]},
           {name:'Miau', accessories:[]}
         ];
```

Convendría crear una referencia de todo el objeto buscando por el nombre, así, ya usas esa referencia para todo: si la referencia es `undefined` no hay gatos con ese nombre, esa validación queda hecha. Luego, la usas para verificar si el accesorio existe, y si no existe, usas la referencia para agregarlo.

En tu lógica parece que los accesorios son globales a todos los gatos, pero esto no tendría sentido, pues ¿cómo sabrías que `Misu` ya tiene un `Collar`?.

Si me equivoco, y `accessories` debe ir en el objeto global, entonces colócalo allí, y para verificar haz: `if ( cats.accessories.includes(catAccessory) )`, y para agregar: `cats.accessories.push(catAccessory)`, aunque, en ese caso sería interesante que nos digas cómo sabrás a qué gato pertenece qué accesorio ¿?

```js
let cats = [{
    name: 'Misu',
    accessories: []
  },
  {
    name: 'Miau',
    accessories: []
  }
];
const addCatAccessory = function(catName, catAccessory) {

  /*
    Referencia a todo el gato
    que servirá para verificar/agregar sus accesorios
  */
  let theCat = cats.find(o => o.name === catName);

  /*
    Si no hay gatos con catName
    la referencia será undefined
  */
  if (theCat === undefined) throw new Error(`El gato ${catName} no existe`);

  /*
    Usamos includes para ver si
    el accesorio está en el array accessories
  */
  if ( theCat.accessories.includes(catAccessory) ) {
    throw new Error(`El gato ${catName} ya tiene el accesorio puesto`)
  }
  theCat.accessories.push(catAccessory);
  return `El accesorio ${catAccessory} fue agregado a ${catName} con éxito`
}
console.log(addCatAccessory('Misu', 'Collar'));
console.log(cats);
console.log(addCatAccessory('Miau', 'Arena'));
console.log(cats);
console.log(addCatAccessory('Misu', 'Casita'));
console.log(cats);

// Casos de error
console.log(addCatAccessory('Misu', 'Collar'));
console.log(addCatAccessory('Fake', 'Collar'));
```

Comment: A. Cedano, de antemano agradezco su colaboración es de mucha ayuda para mí. Esperó seguir contando con su valioso conocimiento. Dios te siga bendiciendo.

Comment: Honestamente pregunto: ¿cuál era la pregunta de OP? Hasta ahora no determinamos qué quiso preguntar, y tampoco lo aclaró.

Comment: @padaleiana ciertamente a OP le faltó elaborar un poco mejor la pregunta, no obstante, el problema se entiende gracias a las diferentes líneas comentadas al inicio y que hacen pensar se trata de un ejercicio. Por eso consideré que era factible dar una respuesta.